# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

Here, I am getting error like this,

## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

My SQL query is like,

```
SELECT * 
FROM `fx_users_attendance` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `fx_account_details` ON fx_account_details.user_id = fx_users_attendance.user_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `fx_departments` ON fx_departments.deptid = fx_account_details.department 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `fx_users` ON fx_users.id = fx_users_attendance.user_id 
WHERE fx_departments.deptid IN(1)
AND fx_users.id IN(5)
AND YEAR(clock_in) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12)
```

What it says actually?

Comment: MayBe `Group by ` should get a column not values ad parameter?!

Comment: use GROUP BY column name not GROUP BY (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should be the syntax of your GROUP BY clause. Simply remove the parentheses and it should be fine.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `fx_users_attendance` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `fx_account_details` ON fx_account_details.user_id = fx_users_attendance.user_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `fx_departments` ON fx_departments.deptid = fx_account_details.department 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `fx_users` ON fx_users.id = fx_users_attendance.user_id 
WHERE fx_departments.deptid IN(1)
AND fx_users.id IN(5)
AND YEAR(clock_in) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12
```

Comment: Thanks @Aioros... I got it.. :)